# System Identification on Scilab

Tags: scilab, data-processing, transfer-function

Is it possible for scilab to identify a system? there are a lot of documentation for MATLAB but in scilab i cant find any. This is the data that Im going to analyze

```
    FREQUENCY    AMPLITUDE       PHASE

    (rad/s)        (cm)          (deg)

    0.5024          10.6        -11.8089

    0.6280           10.7          -21.1299

    0.7388          10.5           -24.3229

    1.2560           10.3           -41.5777

    1.7942           9.60           -59.8070

    3.1400           7.90           -105.6840

    4.1866           8.00           -136.6452

    6.2800           5.10           -221.9617

    7.8500           1.97           -263.1554

    9.4200           0.98           -279.4872
```

These data came from a frequency response test for a system and my goal is finding its transfer function using scilab. Unfortunately I cant post an image of my data

Answer (score 0):

You might try the function `frep2tf`, furthermore `help identification` might be interesting for you.